# Disabling a Select When a CheckBox is Checked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, checkbox, javascript

I am working on a large product and for the life of me I cannot get this to work.
My problem, is that the id of the checkboxes and the drop-down boxes are dynamic so I simply cannot reference them and I cannot edit the html to give them another. I can however, contain them in a Div and give that a class name to reference them (div.blaaah select).

I have been trying to research and write some JS to disable the drop-down boxes when a checkbox is selected but with the referencing issues I cannot do it.

Also I want this to apply many many areas on the page (around 65 checkboxes disable corresponding pairs of drop-down boxes) - for example:

[image: example]

as each div containg a drop-down box is the next element after the div containing the checkbox to disable it I thought I could use .next() or something but my skills with Js just arent up to scratch!

I have attempted a host of things but the generel idea I am going for is along the lines of the following shambles of an attempt:

```
$(".NACheck input").click(function() {
$(this).next(".importSelect select").disabled=true;
});
```

This is the heirachy of the elements:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <div class="checkNA">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <INPUT: CHECKBOX />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div>
    <div class="importSelect">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>
                <SELECT />
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div>
    <div class="RelSelect">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>
                <SELECT />
              <span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I am a fan of using `<table>` when needs must, but that is just an amazingly over complicated use of formatting!

Comment: This is not my work but also, the product is an insanely complicated system, in essence it is a huuuge cms system and I am editing it customer side to make it do what they want

Comment: Tables are used for practicality in this case and not for lazy formatting [=

Comment: I'll have to take your word for it @Phil, because it's horrible in it's current state! Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".NACheck input").click(function() {
    $('select', $(this).parents('.container-of-each-line')).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `select boxs` are `next two elements` after `checkbox`

add `onchange` or `onclick` event to each checkbox as

```
this.nextSibling.disabled = this.checked;
this.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = this.checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

```
$(this).parents('div containing checkbox').next().children().attr("disabled", true);
```

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/ZBymu/

Comment: I have just added the heriachy in the html to bottom of my question as I didnt really make it very clear

Comment: can you give unique ids to each and every checkbox and corresponding two select boxes?

Comment: $('.checkNA :checkbox').click(function() {
    $(".importSelect select").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".RelSelect select").attr("disabled", true);
});  here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvG9F/

Comment: Unfortunately not, then life would be too easy. I can only add a unique ID to a div that contains the check/drops

Comment: then give dynamic id to the _table_ which contains the whole row of checkbox and two select boxes(say in a for loop like <table id="row-table{somedynamicvalue}">) and then fire _onclick_ event from checkbox passing that table's dynamic id(like disableSelect({somedynamicvalue});). Now, script would be: function disableSelect(dynamicId) {
    $("#row-table"+dynamicId+" select").attr("disabled", true);
}   hope it's correct this time!

Comment: Unfortunately I cant, without changing a subversion of the live system, and creating a new build on the servers the only HTML that I can change whatsoever is a class name of the containing div. However I have worked it out! I used basically used some jQuery to go back the parent(), then on to the next() parent, then find() the dropbox... took me much longer than what it was worth but very satisfied now, thank you so so much for your help!

Comment: this....  =    var parent = $(this).closest("td.ct_group_table_cell");
  
     parent.next().find(".importSelect select").attr("disabled", (this.checked) ? "disabled" : "");
     parent.next().next().find(".satisSelect select").attr("disabled", (this.checked) ? "disabled" : "");